# ChartKick Gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Chartkick Gem for generation of chart for my rails application.

I have the following 2 tables.

1. Table A : Item_History
2. Table B : Items

They are linked via the itemId in Table A to Id in Table B.

With the below code for ChartKick, I am trying to instead of grouping via the ItemID (Table A), i want to be able to get the Item name from Table B.

```
<%= pie_chart Item_History.where("record = ?", 16).group(:itemid).sum(:price) %>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This `Item_History` seems weird to me. Shouldn't that be just `ItemHistory`? And also post the schema of your both tables.

Comment: Yeah it is ItemHistory. i just mistype it. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the issue here.

I need to include the following to the codes to get the name.

```
<%=pie_chart ItemHistory.includes(:items).where("record = ?", 16).group(:itemname).sum(:price) %>
```

Add in the ".includes(:items)".